# How to attach file to sharepoint document library by using REST API/ecma script?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

How can I attach file to document library by using REST API in my SharePoint 2013 app ?

Please help me to achieve this task.

Here's my code so far:

```
 function dofunc() {
        alert('upload function');
        var control = document.getElementById("ufile");
        control.addEventListener("change", fdocattach, false);
    }
    var file;
    var contents;
```

```
function fdocattach(event) {
    alert('upload event attach');
    var i = 0,
        files = event.srcElement.files,
        len = files.length;
    alert(len);
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        console.log("Filename: " + files[i].name);
        console.log("Type: " + files[i].type);
        console.log("Size: " + files[i].size + " bytes");
    }

    if (!window.FileReader) {
        alert("The FileSystem APIs are not fully supported in this browser.");
        return false;
    }

    if (files.length > 0) {
        alert('file.length > 0')
        file = files[0];
        fileName = file.name;
        alert(fileName);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = fonload;

        reader.onerror = function (event) {
            console.error("File reading error " + event.target.error.code);
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
    return false;
}

function _arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    alert('arrayBuffer method');
    var binary = ''
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer)
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    alert(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i])
    }
    return binary;

}

function fonload(event) {
    alert('fonload');
    contents = event.target.result;
    var scriptbase1 = hostUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
    $.getScript(scriptbase1 + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', fonload2);
}

function fonload2() {
    alert('fonload2');
    var contents2 = _arrayBufferToBase64(contents);
    var myfilename = file.name;
    //var myurl = "https://amexfoods.sharepoint.com/sites/developersite/_api/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + myfilename + "')";
    alert(appweburl);
    var createitem = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    //alert(createitem.)

    createitem.executeAsync({
        url: "https://amexfoods.sharepoint.com/sites/developersite/_api/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items(1)/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + myfilename + "')",
        method: "POST",
        binaryStringRequestBody: true,
        body: contents2,
        success: fsucc,
        error: ferr,
        state: "Update"
    });

    function fsucc(data) {
        alert('success');
    }

    function ferr(data) {
        alert('error\n\n' + data.statusText + "\n\n" + data.responseText);
    }
```

Comment: Have you gotten anywhere code-wise? By seeing your code so far it is so much easier to help you

Comment: hi robert lindgren can u see my code now i have added code pls check my code and please help me Robert

Comment: Sorry but I'm not the one that will help you out (since my knowledge in this specific area of SharePoint is limited), but I'm sure we have many other members that will help you out :)

Comment: Thanks for the your response Robert, please let me know if anybody can help me.

Comment: What errors are you receiving?

Comment: i am getting undefined ,undefined ,undefined three times it  is giving

Comment: i have added alert boxes to all the functions,when i the code comes to execute at createitem.executeAsync() here i am getting undefined undefined,not success alert executing

Comment: is there any problem with url which is in REST api url

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `appweburl` and  `hostUrl` variables are not defined. Also, unless you are running this code cross-site you should be using site relative url's and if you are running it cross-site you should **not** post the full URL to your site in public forums.

My guess is these lines:

```
var scriptbase1 = hostUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
$.getScript(scriptbase1 + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', fonload2);
....
alert(appweburl);
var createitem = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
createitem.executeAsync({
    url: "https://mysite.com/sites/site1/_api/list...
```

Should be something like this:

```
var hostUrl = "/";
var scriptbase1 = hostUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
$.getScript(scriptbase1 + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', fonload2);
....
var appweburl = "/";
alert(appweburl);
var createitem = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
createitem.executeAsync({
    url: appweburl + "_api/list...
```

Where `"/"` is the siterelative/absolute url to the containing site collection

Comment: Thank you for your reply Realistic.I will try this Process .

Comment: hi realistic not working this .i tried with your suggested change but same result .

Comment: You are still receiving the alerts with "undefined"? also does the error alert ever fire?

Comment: Hi realistic now i got sample code its working fine,now i can upload file .Thank you for your support .

Comment: Glad to hear your problem is solved. If this answer was helpful please mark it as the accepted answer.